# System.out.print("") isnt printing before the console is stopped by Scanner(System.in), e.i. cursor is just waiting

Tags: java

Here's the code:

```
private boolean getPlayerAction() {
        while (player.getHandValue() < 21) {
            System.out.print("Do you want to Hit or Stand?: ");
            char c = getInput();
            switch (c) {
                case 'h' -> {
                    player.setCard(dealer.dealCard());
                    System.out.println(player.toString());
                }
                case 's' -> {
                    return true;
                }
                default -> System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again.");
            }
        }
        if (player.getHandValue() > 21) {
            System.out.println("Sorry. You bust.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

private char getInput() {
        String input = in.nextLine();
        if (!input.isEmpty()) return input.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
        return 'b';
    }
```

and here's the output:

```
Dealer is showing 10 with QS 
You have 13 with 3H JC
```

It should have the prompt: "Do you want to Hit or Stand?: " where the blank line is. If I hit enter the output looks like this:

```
Dealer is showing 10 with QS 
You have 13 with 3H JC 

Do you want to Hit or Stand?: Invalid entry, try again.
```

Additional side note, I tried running this with println() instead of print() and it works as it should, but using print() I get the funky weirdness.

Comment: Won't that switch case fall through without a return or break? If I hit, won't it give me new card and then return true?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but why are you using [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html)?

Comment: The switch is more efficient than if-then. And as for falling through, no, it doesn't, the loop works just fine. On a side note, the program works just as expected if I use println() instead of print()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I notice is that you may be well served by adding c.tolowercase() before entering the switch statement. That will guarantee that the player's choice is read in regardless of whether they type h or H (or s or S, as it may be).

I think your problem is probably in how Java handles it's System.out.print() and System.out.println() functions. It may be something to do with trying to continue your output stream with System.out.print() after it has closed the stream for that line if you used System.out.println() for your last output display (the part that tells the player their current hand)?

Unless you have a reason that you absolutely need to use .print(), I'd say just use .println() for it since you said that definitely works if you can't find a reason why .print() doesn't.

EDIT:
Maybe your issue is that .print() doesn't close the output stream, so it runs into an issue when immediately after when you try to open the input stream in what the machine sees as the middle of outputting?

Comment: Thank you for your response. input.toLowerCase() is nested in the getInput function.

Comment: @JReyn I see that now. Apologies for the confusion :)

Comment: I think you may be right, I'm marking this as solved. Thanks for your edit.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to flush the output to see it appear where you're hoping.

Try adding:

```
System.out.flush();
```

right after your `System.out.print("Do you want to Hit or Stand?: ");`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work. I tried adding it both before and after, same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your not showing any of the code that actually prints the statements before the print() line which is likely the code that is actually causing this issue.

Although, for your case you may need to consider calling
`in.next()` instead of `in.nextLine()` when using a `print()` statement instead of a `println()`. Thats just a guess since the other code is missing.

The code could also be optimized a lot better but, I am guessing this is some school assignment so it might not matter.

Comment: No, just for fun. I am using the println() as its giving me the results I want, but as for using next() v. nextLine() I've tried both to no avail. Also, the statements that are not shown are println()'s  which I've tried turning into print( outout + "\n") and still having same issue.  Lastly, optimized how?

Comment: Not seeing the rest of my code, I'm curious as to where you think "a lot" of optimization would be? I'm not a novice, so please, expand on where you think my code could be improved.